# How to zoom a d3.js DotsChart instead of lineChart

Tags: d3.js, zooming

i want zoom a dot chart like a line but each point are duplicated by zoom step.

```
g.updateCurve = function(_){
    // Update the line path.
    this.select(".line")
    .attr("d", line);

    // add each point
    this.selectAll('.circle').data(data).enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return xScale (d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return yScale (d.ySpeed); })
    .attr("r", function(d) {return rScale (d.xSpeed); });

    return this;
};
```

how can I change for a proper zoom ?

I work on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albanlopez/Egd2q/3/)

Answer (score 2):

it need to costruct DOM.Circle.data before the update fonction:

```
g.selectAll('circle').data(data).enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot");
```

and juste update .attr() on zoom event

```
// for update Attribute of line and Dots on ZoomEvent
g.updateCurve = function(){
    // Update the line path.
    this.select(".line")
    .attr("d", line);

    // add each point
    this.selectAll('circle')
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return xScale (d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return yScale (d.ySpeed); })
    .attr("r", function(d) {return rScale (d.xSpeed); });

    return this;
};
```

[Working exemple on  JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albanlopez/Egd2q/6/)